# Is it possible to run a Web Worker on my index.html in my angular app?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have my angular app working fine. I just want to add some computations at the beginning of the app on my index.html in order to do that I added the following line at the beginning of that index.html file:

```
<script type="module" src="myScript.js"></script>
```

The myScript.js file is in the same directory as the index.html But it seems like it does not recognize it. If I go to inspect the site I can see the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/myScripts.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Anyone knows why that is and how can I fix it? I do not know why it is looking for it like that. Any help would be greatly appreciated

I tried this before. It seems like it looks for the file in localhost:4200/myScript.js and does not find it. I have tried spinning up a new server and calling it directly from localhost:5555/myScript.js and it is able to find it! but it does not run it. It gives me the error: `Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

Here is what I tried

```
<script type="module">
    if (window.Worker) {
        console.log('index');
        const worker = new Worker('http://localhost:5555/app.worker.ts', {type: 'module'});
        worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
            console.log(`page got message: ${data}`);
        };
        worker.postMessage('helloMatcha');
  }
```

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? Is your server responding for requests for `myScripts.js` at the right path?

Comment: That's so not the Angular way. For a simple app you would probably make a simple service for this (provideIn: 'root', and call the methods doing the computations from the root component. Or you would call it from your main.ts. It's probably better to create a typsescript file for your computations, because it is a bit advanced to setup angular for js files also.

Comment: I know it may not be the angular way but My app is a little slow so we are pre-loading all data using a web worker on initialization. The fastest results are if I get to start my web worker from my index.html file

Comment: then just use the angular way of using webworkers: https://angular.io/guide/web-worker

Comment: @R_Ice thats the issue I have tried. I have         

const worker = new Worker('./app.worker.ts', { type: 'module' });

but I cant seem to be able to post anything to that file

Comment: did you restart your server and cleared cache?

Comment: @R_Ice I did restart server, cleared cache! Also, when I try it from main.ts it does work but it is too late. I have noticed that index.html happens right at the exact moment I would like it to go

Answer (score 0):

Try without type="module", then you can try to move the custom script to a src/asset location (or something like that) and add the file to scripts section in angular.json.

```
"scripts": [
 "src/assets/custom.js"
  ]
```

Comment: I tried this before. It seems like it looks for the file in localhost:4200/myScript.js and does not find it. I have tried spinning up a new server and calling it directly from localhost:5555/myScript.js and it is able to find it! but it does not run it. It gives me the error: Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.